# Html ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

My error = ReferenceError: document is not defined

```
document.getElementsByClassName("text_status").innerHTML = 'hello'
```

I am trying to change the text of an element in my html.
This is the beginning of my html file
I am running this code in my electron JS app

```
    <script defer src="js/appfunction.js"></script>
    <script defer src="js/myscript.js"></script>
```

What I am doing wrong or what should I change ?

Comment: Where/how are you executing this code?  This is in-browser JavaScript, but you've added the `node.js` tag which implies otherwise.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements that use the given class name, so you need to use array index, `document.getElementsByClassName("text_status")[0].innerHTML = 'some html';`

Answer (score 0):

The [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object is only available after
the [DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Using_the_W3C_DOM_Level_1_Core)
has been built and not beforehand.

Using [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) in
your [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag(s)
is
correct though best practice now dictates one places any `<script>` tags between the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags.

When updating the page element with a class name of `text-status`, if you are only updating the text within the element
then you can use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) instead
of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Lastly, [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
returns an array of objects. A particular object can be access by referring to its index number.
EG: `document.getElementsByClassName()[0]`. To access all objects, one
can [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) through them.

> TIP: The trick to remembering if a particular Javascript method returns an array of objects is
> by its name. If the method name contains a plural word (IE: Element**s** vs Element) then it will usually return an
> array and not a single object.

If the element value you need to change is a unique element then you should refer to that element by `id` and
use `document.getElementById('text-status')`.
See [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for more
information.

---

Not knowing how your html document is constructed and assuming the value is to be changed by your render process, I have
created the below code for your understanding.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="text_status">Div 1</div>
        <div class="text_status">Div 2</div>
        <div class="text_status">Div 3</div>

        <div id="text_status">Div 4</div>
    </body>
    
    <script src="appFunction.js">
    <!-- <script src="myscript.js"> -->
</html>
```

---

`appfunction.js` (render process)

```js
// Use element(s) class name
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('text_status');
console.log(elements); // Testing
elements[1].innerText = 'Div 2 - Updated'; // Change second element

// Use element id
let element = document.getElementById('text_status');
console.log(element); // Testing
element.innerText = 'Div 4 - Updated';
```

> If the changing value of your element is to come from your main process then you should re-word your question
> as the answer will be more involved.